# Can I restore cookies from Chrome in Cypress?

Tags: javascript, e2e-testing, cypress

I don't want to log in every time I start tests. Can I get cookies from Chrome? Or from the previous Cypress run?

Answer (score 1):

I have a tried this way, create a `login()` test in `commands.js` file and grab the `session` details and pass it in `Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce("some_session");` I have written the test like this. Login once for rest of the tests.

*note: After login > Chrome > press F12 > Application > Cookies > get the session details*

//cypress/support/commands.js

```
Cypress.Commands.add('login', () => {
   cy.visit('/')
   cy.get('#email_id').type("some email");
   cy.get('#password_field').type("some password");
   cy.get('#submit_button_id').click();
});



describe('Preserve the login details for every test', () => {
    beforeEach(() => {
         cy.wait(1000);
         cy.clearCookies();
         cy.login();
         Cypress.Cookies.preserveOnce("some_session");
      });

    it('Verify some tab here Test-1', function(){
         //some test to do..
       })

    it('Verify some button here Test-2', function(){
        //some test to do..
       })

     it('Verify some text here Test-3', function(){
         //some test to do..
        })

    });
```